# Scrolling to an anchor link with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a link at the top my page which is linked to #here. How can I make the page scroll down to the anchor link with the #here? I've been going to Google and jQuery site, but don't know what to do. The JS code is all I've got.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
       <a class="link" href="#here">Here</a>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
       <a id="here"></a>
       <p>Some text...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.link').click(function() {
    $(this).scroll()
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add:

```
$('.link').click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#here').offset().top }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: you didn't prevent the default behavior here.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the browser's location to the hashtag, then the browser should scroll to that location.

```
$('.link').click(function() {
   windows.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Comment: Thank you as well for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin has some nice functionality and features added to it (like different animations):
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

"All the matched elements will be scrolled, for example:

`$('div.pane').scrollTo(...);//all divs w/class pane`

If you need to scroll the window (screen), then use:

`$.scrollTo(...);//the plugin will take care of this`"